# Preventing a second click on RadioButton if it was already checked

Tags: java, android

I am creating a small quiz app. As the question suggests, how do I prevent a second click without disabling the button? When I click twice on a radio button it adds 2 points instead of 1. Very much appreciated!

Here's a picture of my app:

[image]

```
public void question1 (View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question1_9:
            if (checked) {
                scoreForRadioButtons += 1;
            }

        case R.id.question1_8:
            if (checked) {
                break;
            }
        case R.id.question1_7:
            if (checked) {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

---

SOLVED

This is what I did: just add 'break;' on the correct answer.

```
public void question1 (View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question1_9:
            if (checked) {
                pointForQ1 = 1;
                break;
            }
        case R.id.question1_8:
            if (checked) {
                pointForQ1 = 0;
            }
        case R.id.question1_7:
            if (checked) {
                pointForQ1 = 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had some means of detecting that the user unchecked the RadioButton, then you could subtract "1" on unchecking and add "1" on checking. [Useful link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener))

Comment: Please don't add solution in question and solved to title, add your solution as an answer and accept the answer that works for you see [tour] to learn more

Comment: I guess... 8 movies?

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**

You can set the `clickable` attribute to false for the `RadioButton` after it is clicked if you really want to using the following:

```
myRadioButton.setClickable(false);
```

**Long Answer:**

Don't use radio buttons for this. Users should be able to click a radio button as many times as they want without anything happening like incrementing the score in your case. It's a standard convention of a radio button that once selected, no new code is executed if it is selected again and again. *Note this is only if the state of the radio button hasn't changed during selections (state meaning whether it's selected or not)*.

The way your app is using (or wants to use) `RadioButtons` is not correct. I'd recommend using buttons for this, where you could do the following:

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to make it visible to the user that they clicked a button, you can do a few things (change it's text, change the background colour). For this example, you can change the background colour with this:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);   // or whatever colour you choose
```

If you want to do this add the following to your imports:

```
import android.graphics.Color
```

Comment: Much appreciated with your reply! I have learned something new. I have attached an image that shows a small part of my app to show what I'm trying to accomplish. However, about the buttons, how would the user see if the user has selected a button?

Comment: @AVO757 You're welcome! I edited my post to address your question. Please upvote/accept my answer if you feel it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just don't want to click that radio button two times, After radio button is clicked,
add `view.setEnabled(false);`or
`view.setClickable(false);` to prevent it click again

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the second click on a checked radio button, make that radio disabled

*radioButton.setEnabled(false);*

Answer (score 0):

Disable a clicked button and enable it when another is checked

```
 public void question1 (View view) {
    //will enable all buttons
    Integer[] buttons = {R.id.question1_9, R.id.question1_8, R.id.question1_7};
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        findViewById(buttons[i]).setEnabled(true);
    }

    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) view;

    if (button.isChecked()){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question1_9:
                    scoreForRadioButtons ++;
                    //will disable clicked button
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
            case R.id.question1_8:

                    break;
            case R.id.question1_7:

                    break;
        }
    }
```